# Issues with display: block in Safari browser past version 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I'm facing the following issue:

I'm working with a site which shows additional information on hover. Whole functionality for hovering and display of content is done via JQuery and it works perfectly in all browsers except for Safari browser past version 6. Specifically it appears that display: block is not being applied properly and content is not showing, even though I can actually see the changes being made when I hover over the elements in the console.

This is the code that does the change

```
 function applyScriptIfNeeded(li) { 
           var parent = $('.jCarouselLite:not(.paging)');
            $('.someClass', li).hover(function() {
                var someItem = this;                    
                var child = $('.serviceInfoWrapper', someItem);
                var display = child.css('display');
                child.css('display', 'block');  
                if (child.is(":visible")) {
                    if (!contains(parent, child))  {
                        child.css('display', display);
                        var pos = $(someItem).offset();

                        $(document).scroll(function() {
                            child.css('top', $(someItem).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop());
                        });
                        child.css( {
                            display: 'block',
                            position: 'fixed',
                            top: pos.top -  $(window).scrollTop(),
                            left: pos.left - $(child).width() - 30 - $(window).scrollLeft()
                        });
                    }                           
                }
            },
            function() {
                var someItem = this;                    
                var child = $('.serviceInfoWrapper', someItem);
                child.css('display', 'none');
            });
        }
```

The HTML element to which I'm applying this function is really just a simple div so I'm not sure what might these problems.

Can someone help me with this ? Did anyone else encounter this type of issues with Safari before ?